# Get json value from byte using rust

Tags: json, rust, byte

I need to get the name from a `base64` value, I tried like following but I didn't able to parse it and get the name property, any idea how can I do it ?

```
extern crate base64;
use serde_json::Value;
fn main() {


    let v = "eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ";

    let bytes = base64::decode(v).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", bytes);
   
   
    let v: Value = serde_json::from_slice(bytes);
    

}
```

The value represnt json like

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "iat": 1516239022
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1df0f644a139f8d526a44af8abf78e8e

**At the end I need to print `"name": "John Doe"`**

this is the decoded value

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Masklinn explains why you have an error, and you should read his answer.

But IMO the simplest and safest solution is to use [serde's derive](https://serde.rs/derive.html) to decode into the desired structure:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;

/// a struct into which to decode the thing
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Thing {
    name: String,
    // add the other fields if you need them
}

fn main() {
    let v = "eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ";
    let bytes = base64::decode(v).unwrap(); // you should handle errors
    let thing: Thing = serde_json::from_slice(&bytes).unwrap();
    let name = thing.name;
    dbg!(name);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Denys has provided for the usual way to use serde, and you should definitely apply their solution if that's an option (if the document is not dynamic).

However:

> https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1df0f644a139f8d526a44af8abf78e8e

Have you considered at least following the indications of the compiler? The Rust compiler is both pretty expressive and very strict, if you give up at every compilation error without even trying to understand what's happening, you'll have a *very* hard time.

If you try to compile your snippet, the first thing it tells you is

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:43
   |
12 |     let v: Value = serde_json::from_slice(bytes);
   |                                           ^^^^^
   |                                           |
   |                                           expected `&[u8]`, found struct `Vec`
   |                                           help: consider borrowing here: `&bytes`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&[u8]`
                 found struct `Vec<u8>`
```

and while it doesn't always work out perfectly, the compiler's suggestion is spot-on: `base64` has to allocate space for the return value so it yields a `Vec`, but `serde_json` doesn't really care where the data comes from so it takes a slice. Just referencing (applying the `&` operator) the vec allows rustc to coerce it to a slice.

The second suggestion is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:20
   |
12 |     let v: Value = serde_json::from_slice(bytes);
   |            -----   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `Value`, found enum `Result`
   |            |
   |            expected due to this
   |
   = note: expected enum `Value`
              found enum `Result<_, serde_json::Error>`
```

which doesn't provide a solution but a simple `unwrap` would do for testing. However you really want to read up on [Rust error handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) as `Result` is very much the normal way to signal fallibility / errors, and thus like compiler errors you will also encounter it a lot.

Anyway that yields a proper [`serde_json::value::Value`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html), which you can manipulate the normal way e.g.

```rust
v.get("name").and_then(Value::as_str));
```

will return an `Option<&str>` of value `None` if the key is missing or not mapping to a string, and `Some(s)` if the key is present and mapping to a string: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5025d399644694b4b651c4ff1b9125a1

Comment: But yes, you're right. I largely prefer the safety of derive based deserialization but I should have explained the error and how to use the Value too. Good point.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Oh wow sorry I don't know why I thought you were callled Daniel. Fixed. And agreed your solution is the much better one, hence why I called it the usual way to use serde (and upvoted it). I just wanted to provide the "bare" fix for the issue demonstrated.